# Get distinct entity objects from NSMutableArray using NSPredicate in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` which has entity class object as its objects.
Now I want to remove the distinct objects from it. Consider following example

```
Entity *entity = [[Entity alloc] init]; 
entity.iUserId = 1;
entity.iUserName = @"Giri"
[arr addObject:entity];

Entity *entity = [[Entity alloc] init]; 
entity.iUserId = 2;
entity.iUserName = @"Sunil"
[arr addObject:entity];

Entity *entity = [[Entity alloc] init]; 
entity.iUserId = 3;
entity.iUserName = @"Giri"
[arr addObject:entity];
```

Now I want only two objects in the `Array` by removing the duplicate iUserName. I know the way by iteration but I want it without iterating it like `predicate` or some other way.
If anyone knows then please help me.
I had tried using `[arr valueForKeyPath:@"distinctUnionOfObjects.iUsername"];` but it does not return me the entired object.

*This question is totally different than the questions which are asked previously. Previously asked question is for getting the distinct objects is correct but they uses looping & I don't want this. I want it from `NSPredicate` or any other simple option which avoids looping.*

Comment: "in iphone sdk" - Thanks for that! It has been a long time since somebody used this correctly (instead of the inappropriate "using Xcode" term).

Comment: I remember I have solved this kind of question 3-4 times. So never feel shy to search/google.

Comment: @AKV I want the distinct elements by comparing the entity from the entity class object. Also I want to avoid the for loop. Is it possible through predicate or any other option

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: You can't do what you want to without looping over the array manually and building up a new array. The answer below won't work because it assumes that there are only at most two duplicates.

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Entity *entity in arr)
{
    BOOL hasDuplicate = [[filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iUserName == %@", entity.iUserName]] count] > 0;

    if (!hasDuplicate)
    {
        [filteredArray addObject:entity];
    }
}
```

This will look for duplicates in the filtered array as it builds it.

**Begin Original Answer**

You can't use an `NSSet` because the `Entity` instances would have to return `NSOrderedSame` in `compareTo:`, which isn't a good idea since you shouldn't use names as unique identifiers.

You can use predicates, but they'll still loop over the array in an `O(n^2)` time without some optimization.

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Entity *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iUserName == %@", evaluatedObject.iUserName]] count] > 1;
}]];
```

That'll work fine. You could make it even faster by sorting the array by the `iUserName` property first and doing a linear scan over the sorted array (stopping when you see the first duplicate). That's a lot of work if you're dealing with small sample sizes (say, under ten thousand or so). It's probably not worth your time, so just use the code above.

Comment: I had tried your solution but it does not works. I used following code NSArray *filteredArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Entity *entity, NSDictionary *bindings)
    {
        return [[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iUsername == %@", exercise.iUsername]] count] > 1;
    }]];

Comment: That should work, yes.

Comment: My array contains total 14 elements out of this, 7 are common so it needs to return 6 elements but it returns 13 elements.

Comment: I take it back - you can't do this without looping manually. `NSPredicate` won't work. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few options (that I can think of).

1. Use a NSSet instead of a NSArray.
2. Use a for loop (but you don't want to iterate through the array)
3. Use a predicate search iUserName to see if the name exists before adding it to the array.

Something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iUserName == 'Giri'"];
NSArray *searchArray = [arr filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```